# LTSpice simulation :Unable to check the output values

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation, ltspice

I am new in LTSpice simulation .I have prepared the [schematic](https://1fichier.com/?pry6gkllu7) of the following DC to DC buck converter design in folder i.e. C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceIV\Rough\ . **My aim is to make  a charger for a smartphone that has 110Vdc input and {5Vdc, 2A} output.**

I don't know which commands are required to be inserted in the schematic using **simulate-> Edit simulation cmd** option to see the results. I want to check the output voltage at the Vout node and Iout value using tester . Also I want to see the waveforms but don't know how to do it . So what changes should I do in schematic ?

**Edit:** By looking at one [LTSpice Buck Converter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGo8XlZ7U4s) on youtube, I added simulate->Edit simulation cmd->Transient->Stop time=100usec. When I click on RUN option, it is not showing any error but there is no waveform window. In the bottom of window of schematic,it is just showing  stepping source 100% and iterations are changing continuously.

[image]
[image]

```
.asc file
    Version 4
    SHEET 1 1700 968
    WIRE 864 -800 768 -800
    WIRE 1008 -800 928 -800
    WIRE -368 -736 -512 -736
    WIRE -240 -736 -368 -736
    WIRE -16 -736 -240 -736
    WIRE 112 -736 -16 -736
    WIRE 240 -736 112 -736
    WIRE 544 -736 240 -736
    WIRE -240 -704 -240 -736
    WIRE -16 -704 -16 -736
    WIRE 112 -704 112 -736
    WIRE 240 -704 240 -736
    WIRE -512 -688 -512 -736
    WIRE -368 -688 -368 -736
    WIRE 768 -672 768 -800
    WIRE 768 -672 608 -672
    WIRE 864 -672 768 -672
    WIRE 1008 -672 1008 -800
    WIRE 1008 -672 928 -672
    WIRE 1056 -672 1008 -672
    WIRE 1152 -672 1056 -672
    WIRE 1216 -672 1152 -672
    WIRE 1504 -672 1216 -672
    WIRE 1616 -672 1504 -672
    WIRE 544 -656 416 -656
    WIRE 544 -608 480 -608
    WIRE 704 -592 608 -592
    WIRE 1056 -592 1056 -672
    WIRE -240 -576 -240 -624
    WIRE 480 -576 480 -608
    WIRE 704 -560 704 -592
    WIRE -512 -544 -512 -608
    WIRE -432 -544 -512 -544
    WIRE -368 -544 -368 -624
    WIRE -368 -544 -432 -544
    WIRE -16 -528 -16 -624
    WIRE 112 -528 112 -624
    WIRE 112 -528 -16 -528
    WIRE 240 -528 240 -640
    WIRE 240 -528 112 -528
    WIRE 304 -528 240 -528
    WIRE 416 -528 416 -656
    WIRE 416 -528 368 -528
    WIRE 544 -528 480 -528
    WIRE -432 -512 -432 -544
    WIRE 1056 -496 1056 -528
    WIRE 1616 -464 1616 -672
    WIRE 480 -432 480 -528
    WIRE 480 -432 336 -432
    WIRE 336 -384 336 -432
    WIRE -704 -320 -880 -320
    WIRE 1616 -320 1616 -384
    WIRE -880 -256 -880 -320
    WIRE -240 -256 -240 -496
    WIRE -80 -256 -240 -256
    WIRE 32 -256 -80 -256
    WIRE 112 -256 32 -256
    WIRE 192 -256 112 -256
    WIRE 336 -256 336 -320
    WIRE 336 -256 272 -256
    WIRE -80 -192 -80 -256
    WIRE 32 -192 32 -256
    WIRE 112 -192 112 -256
    WIRE -880 -144 -880 -192
    WIRE -528 -96 -592 -96
    WIRE -1152 -80 -1664 -80
    WIRE -704 -80 -704 -320
    WIRE -704 -80 -1152 -80
    WIRE -592 -80 -592 -96
    WIRE -592 -80 -704 -80
    WIRE -240 -80 -240 -256
    WIRE -240 -80 -368 -80
    WIRE -80 -80 -80 -128
    WIRE 32 -80 32 -128
    WIRE 112 -80 112 -128
    WIRE 416 -80 416 -528
    WIRE -528 -64 -560 -64
    WIRE -1456 -48 -1568 -48
    WIRE -1264 -48 -1456 -48
    WIRE -560 -48 -560 -64
    WIRE -560 -48 -1264 -48
    WIRE -208 -48 -368 -48
    WIRE -528 -32 -992 -32
    WIRE 1504 -16 1504 -672
    WIRE -528 0 -672 0
    WIRE -208 0 -208 -48
    WIRE 64 0 -208 0
    WIRE 368 0 144 0
    WIRE -240 16 -368 16
    WIRE -1152 32 -1152 -80
    WIRE -528 32 -592 32
    WIRE -240 48 -240 16
    WIRE -1456 64 -1456 -48
    WIRE -864 64 -912 64
    WIRE -736 64 -800 64
    WIRE -1264 80 -1264 -48
    WIRE -1216 80 -1264 80
    WIRE -992 112 -992 -32
    WIRE -912 112 -912 64
    WIRE -912 112 -992 112
    WIRE -736 112 -736 64
    WIRE -672 112 -672 0
    WIRE -672 112 -736 112
    WIRE 416 128 416 16
    WIRE 416 128 240 128
    WIRE -1568 160 -1568 -48
    WIRE -912 160 -912 112
    WIRE -864 160 -912 160
    WIRE -784 160 -800 160
    WIRE -736 160 -736 112
    WIRE -736 160 -784 160
    WIRE -1152 176 -1152 128
    WIRE 416 176 416 128
    WIRE -1152 288 -1152 256
    WIRE -592 288 -592 32
    WIRE -592 288 -1152 288
    WIRE -192 288 -592 288
    WIRE 64 288 -192 288
    WIRE 240 288 240 128
    WIRE 240 288 144 288
    WIRE 672 288 544 288
    WIRE 720 288 672 288
    WIRE 1152 288 1152 -672
    WIRE 1152 288 720 288
    WIRE 416 320 416 256
    WIRE -192 352 -192 288
    WIRE 544 400 544 288
    WIRE 720 416 720 288
    WIRE 768 416 720 416
    WIRE 912 416 848 416
    WIRE 992 416 912 416
    WIRE 992 432 992 416
    WIRE 912 464 912 416
    WIRE -192 480 -192 416
    WIRE 672 480 672 288
    WIRE 1072 512 1024 512
    WIRE 1248 512 1136 512
    WIRE -1664 560 -1664 -80
    WIRE -1568 560 -1568 240
    WIRE -1568 560 -1664 560
    WIRE 384 560 -1568 560
    WIRE 544 560 544 480
    WIRE 544 560 448 560
    WIRE -992 592 -992 112
    WIRE -368 592 -992 592
    WIRE 224 592 -288 592
    WIRE 384 592 224 592
    WIRE 672 592 672 560
    WIRE 672 592 448 592
    WIRE 912 592 912 528
    WIRE 912 592 672 592
    WIRE 960 592 912 592
    WIRE 1024 592 1024 512
    WIRE 1024 592 960 592
    WIRE 1072 592 1024 592
    WIRE 1248 592 1248 512
    WIRE 1248 592 1152 592
    WIRE 1312 592 1248 592
    WIRE 1504 592 1504 64
    WIRE 1504 592 1376 592
    WIRE 224 656 224 592
    WIRE 960 752 960 592
    WIRE 1072 752 960 752
    WIRE 1504 768 1504 592
    WIRE 1504 768 1152 768
    WIRE 224 784 224 736
    WIRE 1072 784 960 784
    WIRE 1504 816 1504 768
    WIRE 960 912 960 784
    WIRE 1504 912 1504 896
    WIRE 1504 912 960 912
    WIRE 1504 928 1504 912
    FLAG -432 -512 0
    FLAG 480 -576 0
    FLAG 112 -80 0
    FLAG 32 -80 0
    FLAG -80 -80 0
    FLAG -240 48 0
    FLAG -192 480 0
    FLAG 704 -560 0
    FLAG 1056 -496 0
    FLAG 224 784 0
    FLAG 992 496 0
    FLAG 1504 928 0
    FLAG -880 -144 0
    FLAG 416 320 0
    FLAG -1456 128 0
    FLAG 1616 -320 0
    FLAG 1648 -528 I_out
    FLAG 1216 -672 V_out
    SYMBOL voltage -512 -704 R0
    WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
    WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName Vin
    SYMATTR Value 110
    SYMBOL polcap -384 -688 R0
    WINDOW 3 24 56 Left 2
    SYMATTR Value 1µ
    SYMATTR InstName Cin
    SYMATTR Description Capacitor
    SYMATTR Type cap
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=16 Irms=0 Rser=7.08m Lser=0
    SYMBOL res -256 -720 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rstartup_1
    SYMATTR Value 75K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL res -256 -592 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rstartup_2
    SYMATTR Value 75K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL res -32 -720 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rsnub2
    SYMATTR Value 110K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL res 96 -720 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rsnub1
    SYMATTR Value 110K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL cap 224 -704 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Csnub
    SYMATTR Value 0.0018µ
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=200 Irms=119m Rser=1.59882 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805C182K2RAC" type="X7R"
    SYMBOL schottky 368 -544 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName Dsnub
    SYMATTR Value RB056L-40
    SYMATTR Description Diode
    SYMATTR Type diode
    SYMBOL ind2 528 -752 R0
    WINDOW 0 -33 39 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 -28 74 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName L1
    SYMATTR Value 120
    SYMATTR SpiceLine Ipk=0.387
    SYMBOL ind2 528 -624 R0
    WINDOW 0 -27 35 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 -19 73 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName L2
    SYMATTR Value 7
    SYMBOL ind2 624 -576 R180
    WINDOW 0 -29 76 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 -19 49 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName L3
    SYMATTR Value 6
    SYMATTR SpiceLine Ipk=8.18
    SYMBOL nmos 368 -80 R0
    SYMATTR InstName M1
    SYMBOL polcap -96 -192 R0
    WINDOW 0 67 8 Right 2
    WINDOW 3 24 56 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName C12
    SYMATTR Value 100n
    SYMATTR Description Capacitor
    SYMATTR Type cap
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=6.3 Irms=0 Rser=0.9 Lser=0 mfg="AVX" pn="TAJD107M006" type="Tantalum"
    SYMBOL zener 48 -128 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D12
    SYMATTR Value UDZV18B
    SYMATTR Description Diode
    SYMATTR Type diode
    SYMBOL polcap 96 -192 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Cvdd
    SYMATTR Value 68µ
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=10 Irms=2.03852 Rser=0.045 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="T520V686M010ATE045" type="Tantalum"
    SYMBOL res 288 -272 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName Raux
    SYMATTR Value 10
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL schottky 320 -384 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Daux
    SYMATTR Value 1N5817
    SYMATTR Description Diode
    SYMATTR Type diode
    SYMBOL res 160 -16 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName Rdrv
    SYMATTR Value 3.65
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL res 400 160 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rsnus
    SYMATTR Value 1.78
    SYMBOL cap -208 352 R0
    WINDOW 3 26 53 Left 2
    SYMATTR Value 470p
    SYMATTR InstName Ccs
    SYMBOL res 160 272 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName Rcs
    SYMATTR Value 100k
    SYMBOL schottky 864 -784 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName D4
    SYMATTR Value B520C
    SYMBOL polcap 1040 -592 R0
    SYMATTR InstName C4
    SYMATTR Value 180µ
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=5 Irms=1.90488 Rser=0.011 Lser=0
    SYMBOL res -272 576 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R13
    SYMATTR Value 4.99k
    SYMBOL res 208 640 R0
    SYMATTR InstName R12
    SYMATTR Value 1.62k
    SYMBOL cap -800 48 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName C13
    SYMATTR Value 1n
    SYMBOL res -768 144 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R11
    SYMATTR Value 100k
    SYMBOL npn2 -1216 32 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Q1
    SYMBOL res -1168 160 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rsc
    SYMATTR Value 3.32k
    SYMBOL cap -1472 64 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Ct
    SYMATTR Value 1n
    SYMBOL res -1584 144 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rt
    SYMATTR Value 17.4k
    SYMBOL res 528 384 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rled
    SYMATTR Value 2.05k
    SYMBOL res 656 464 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rbias
    SYMATTR Value 205
    SYMBOL res 864 400 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R21
    SYMATTR Value 10k
    SYMBOL schottky 928 528 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D5
    SYMBOL cap 976 432 R0
    SYMATTR InstName C21
    SYMATTR Value 10µ
    SYMBOL res 1168 576 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R22
    SYMATTR Value 9.53k
    SYMBOL cap 1136 496 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName C22
    SYMATTR Value 22p
    SYMBOL cap 1376 576 R90
    WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName C23
    SYMATTR Value 10n
    SYMBOL res 1488 800 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rfbb
    SYMATTR Value 1.43K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL res 1488 -32 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rfbt
    SYMATTR Value 4.32K
    SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
    SYMBOL polcap -896 -256 R0
    WINDOW 3 24 56 Left 2
    SYMATTR Value 100n
    SYMATTR InstName Cref
    SYMATTR Description Capacitor
    SYMATTR Type cap
    SYMATTR SpiceLine V=3 Irms=2.25389 Rser=0.025 Lser=0
    SYMBOL schottky 864 -656 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName D3
    SYMATTR Value B520C
    SYMBOL res 1600 -480 R0
    SYMATTR InstName Rout
    SYMATTR Value 1k
    SYMBOL UCC28C40_STEADY -448 -32 R0
    SYMATTR InstName U2
    SYMBOL TCMT1100 416 576 R0
    SYMATTR InstName U1
    SYMBOL TL431 1120 784 R0
    SYMATTR InstName U3
    TEXT 504 -752 Left 2 !K1 L2 L1 L3 1
    TEXT -528 -456 Left 2 !.tran 100u
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48220/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-user3559780).

Comment: Also, change to Alternate solver under Settings->SPICE if your models and schematic is sound and it still doesn't solve.

Comment: @winny but where I am getting wrong? please see zip file in the schematic

Comment: @user3559780 Difficult to say but you approach the "limit" where simulations usually start to fail or nor converge. Vendor-supplied subcircuits can also be a culprit. Did you try the alternate solver? Can you replace the PWM is with just a voltage source PWM pattern and see if the simulation start?

Comment: @winny No I didn't try any other design. I am new in designing the circuit for buck converter and operating the LTSpice software too. I don't know how to replace the PWM is with just a voltage source PWM pattern

Comment: Place a voltage source. Right click. Choose advanced, PWM.